# Solve The Non-Linear Initial Value Problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve The Non-Linear Initial Value Problem:
>   $$y''=\frac{y'}{x}+\frac{x^2}{y'}$$$$y(2)=0,y'(2)=4$$$$y'y''=\frac{(y')^2}{x}+\frac{x^2y'}{y'}$$$$y'y''=\frac{(y')^2}{x}+x^2$$$$[(y')^2]=2y'(y')'=2y'y''$$$$\frac{1}{2}[(y')^2]=\frac{(y')^2}{x}+x^2$$$$u=y'$$$$\frac{1}{2}u'=\frac{u}{x}+x^2$$$$u'=\frac{2u}{x}+2x^2$$$$u'=p(x)+q(x)$$
>   But where to from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I may suggest, it could have been easier to reduce the order from the start.

Let $u=y'$
$$y''=\frac{y'}{x}+\frac{x^2}{y'}\implies u'=\frac{u}{x}+\frac{x^2}{u}$$ Now, use $u=x v$ which leads to $$x v'=\frac x v\implies v v'=1\implies (v^2)'=2\implies v^2=2x+c_1\implies v=\pm \sqrt{2x+c_1}$$ making $$u=\pm x\sqrt{2x+c_1}$$$$y=\int u \,dx=\pm \int x\sqrt{2x+c_1}\,dx+c_2$$ which does not seem to be too complex (let $2x+c_1=t^2$)

I am sure that you can take it from here.